# How to sort array by index value in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

Hi i have some question what i want to achieve is to sort progress in index 1
how can i do it with mongodb? i try some code but cannot achieve it

```
{ "fb_id" : "user1", "progress" : [  1, 20 ] }
{ "fb_id" : "user2", "progress" : [  2, 10 ] }
{ "fb_id" : "user3", "progress" : [  3 ] }
```

the result i expected is some kind like this

```
{ "fb_id" : "user2", "progress" : [  10 ] }
{ "fb_id" : "user1", "progress" : [  20 ] }
```

It is that i can achieve it through some basic mongodb query?
Thank you

Comment: follow the link" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074614/how-do-mongodb-multi-keys-sort . you may get your answer..

Comment: Wow i spend an hour looking for this. thank you this is what i need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably more complete:

```
db.collection.find(
    { "progress.1": {$exists: true} },
    { _id:0, fb_id: 1, progress: {$slice: [-1, 1]}}
).sort({"progress.1": 1})
```

So, matching, projecting and sorting to your desired result. The key is in the positional notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot i messed up when try to choose the index with "progress[1]". i got it now how to choose array index from your solution. Thank you